# C++ Text Adventure Game: 2D Array's as a map

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

OK, so Im working on a pretty simple Text Adventure game. Right now I have a functioning menu, and a very simple "battle mode" which will be converted into a random encounter as soon as I can. What Im having trouble with right now though is the map.

The idea is to use a 2D Array system as a map, with locations being stored as co-ordinates (if that makes sense.) You can enter 4 directions, "North, East, South and West" to move around, and there are 3 types places you can go. A field, a forest, and a castle. And the map itself, is 5 by 6 in size.

What I want to do is make it so you start in the centre at co-ordinates 2, 2 and you can move around to, say a field for example (designated by a 1 with the integers at the top) it says "You are in a field" and do similar stuff for moving towards the castle, the forests, etc. I also want it to tell the player if they try move to a location marked with a 0 that they can't go there and stop them from moving.

Has anyone got any advice?

EDIT: OK, so I ran through my program again and I've managed to get rid of some errors but I still have a bunch more left (26 to be exact, and 1 warning.)
Is anyone willing to offer me some suggestions?

```
#pragma once
#include "Map.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Map::Map()
{
}

void main()
{
    // Declare variables & functions
    int locationy;
    int locationx;

    char oper;
    char location;

    int pond = 0;
    int field = 1;
    int forest = 2;
    int castle = 3;

    int mapy;
    int mapx;
    int map;

    //These two values declare the start location on the array map for the player
    int mapy = 3;
    int mapx = 3;

    //These two variables track your current position on the map
    mapy = 2;
    mapx = 2;

    map[locationy][locationx];

    //Declares the amount of space within an array
    int map[6][6] = 
    {
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        { 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0 },
        { 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0 },
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };

    //Asks the player where they want to go around the map
    cout << "Where to?" << endl;

    //Request for user to enter an direction (I.e., North, East, South, West.)
    cout << "Please choose  North, East, South or West" << endl;

    //Displays the inputted values
    cin >> oper;

    //Pauses system so we can see what the program does
    system("pause");

    //Checks input from the player
    if (cin == "North")
    {
        //Moves location upwards on the y axis
        if (map[locationx][locationy + 1] != 0) { locationy += 1; };
        else { cout << "That is water, dude. Swimming in platemail is NOT recommended.\n";
    }

    //Checks input from the player
        if (cin == "East")
    {
        //Moves location to the right on the x axis
        if (map[locationx + 1][locationy] != 0) { locationy += 1; };
        else { cout << "That is water, dude. Swimming in platemail is NOT recommended.\n";
    }

    //Checks input from the player
    if (cin == "South")
    {
        //Moves location downwards on the y axis
        if (map[locationx][locationy - 1] != 0) { locationy += 1; }
        else { cout << "That is water, dude. Swimming in platemail is NOT recommended.\n";
    }

    //Checks input from the player
    if (cin == "West")
    {
        //Moves location to the left on the x axis
        if (map[locationx - 1][locationy] != 0) { locationy += 1; }
        else { cout << "That is water, dude. Swimming in platemail is NOT recommended.\n"

    };
}

Map::~Map()
{
    ;
}
```

Comment: `if (map[locationx][locationy + 1] != 0) { locationy += 1; } else { cout << "That is water, dude. Swimming in platemail is NOT recommended.\n" }`

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! This kind of question is probably better suited to this site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. On codereview you are likely to find more people who can answer your question in a way that is more helpful for you in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll try posting there as soon as that 40 min time passes. In the meantime is there possibly any advice you could offer me regardless?

Comment: On Code Review we can help you improve your working code, however that would not be a good place to ask how to write new functionality to your code (that is explicitly off-topic as "code that is not written yet" therefore not reviewable).

Comment: Where would you suggest I ask about for how to write new functionality?

Comment: I see you posted a [modified version of your question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/158361/c-text-adventure-game-2d-arrays-as-a-map) on Code Review, mentioning you were needing some help with errors, which is actually what Stack Overflow is meant for...

Comment: Well can you help me with some of the errors please because debugging is a nightmare. Visual Studio's Intellisense doesn't always seem to offer good suggestions on how to fix a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to C++. Now, you made the basic beginner mistake, which is writing imperative code. C++ is object oriented, which is the key in using it. Makes your code far more effective.

What you should start with in such a case is identifying what parts your project has, what things could be identified as classes. You did so with Map, but what you missed was to create a class that wraps everything, like Game.

Here is my proposal, with many parts not implemented so far.

First, numbers that stand for some terrain are ugly. Let's replace them by an enum:

```
enum class Terrain: unsigned char {
    pond = 0,
    field = 1,
    forest = 2,
    castle = 3
}
```

From now on, you can write Terrain::pond whenever a pond is meant. Makes the code more readable.

Now for a class layout (in Game.h):

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include "Terrain.h"
//alternatively, define Terrain here instead of making it a separate header

class Game {

public:

    Game();

    Game(const string& file_name);
    //Game(file_name) is something you might want to do later -
    //create an instance of Game based on a file that contains a map,
    //maybe more data, instead of hard-coding such things

    void run();

private:

    vector<vector<Terrain> > map;
    //arrays are something you want to avoid. Use std::vector instead.

    unsigned int location_x, location_y;

    bool game_running;
    //aka not has ended

    void evaluate_step();
    //this method is repeated and repeated until the game ends
    //and contains the order in which every step is evaluated

    void handle_input();
    //Takes cin and does something with it

    void evaluate_position();
    //takes the position, gets the terrain from the position,
    //does what happens on that terrain

    void print();
    //prints the whole map to the console

    void set_default_map();
    //sets map to the data you have in your code,
    //to be used until reading from file is implemented
}
```

Now we create the empty constructor to create the defaults (in Game.cpp):

```
Game::Game(){

    set_default_map();
    location_x = ...;
    location_y = ...;
    game_running = true;
}
```

run will simply repeat evaluate step all over:

```
void Game::run(){

    while(game_running){
        evaluate_step();
    }
}

void Game::evaluate_step(){

    handle_input();
    print();
    evaluate_terrain();
}
```

Now, I could go into detail, but I think that this should give you some idea how such a structure could look like. Basic idea is to divide and divide in order to get a clean overview, to create readability.

If you have questions in regard to this proposed class, I'll edit this answer.

In your main, it would be called like that:

```
#include "Game.h"

int main(){

    Game game;
    game.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Now for the errors of your code:

1. You need to write int main instead of void main. void main looks like Java syntax.
2. mapy and mapx are declared two times: `int mapy;` and `int mapy=3;`. That is not allowed. Either remove the first declaration or make the assignment no declaration (`int mapy;` and `mapy=3;`, although I'd prefer to remove the first declaration).
3. No idea what you want with `map[locationy][locationx];`. It's no valid code in any way.
4. map is also declared twice, with two different types (int and int[][]). Remove the first declaration.
5. In all of your cases for cin, your conditions are badly formated. There should not be a semicolon after if-brackets, `if(..){..}else{..}`, not `if(..){..};else{..}`. Also, in every case, there is a bracket missing.
6. What's the difference between mapx and locationx? mapx is set but locationx is used? I deleted mapx and mapy and set locationx and locationy to 2 instead.
7. location is not used. What's it for?
8. You define pond, field etc but you don't use it.
9. main does not need pragma once (neither would it need guards)
10. oper is not used. You probably want to change your if-conditions like if (oper == "North") et cetera. For that you'd need to change the type of oper. A char can only hold one character. You could use char*, but pointers are bad, so better go with string (you need to `#include <string>` for that)
11. The reading in and evaluating is done only once. Do one step and the program ends. Not what you want, I guess - you might want to put a loop around it, like `bool running = true; while(running){...}`
12. For any direction, the location is changed in the same way.

Changed those to make it running (but you should really really change the design):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

void print_water_warning() {
    cout << "That is water, dude. Swimming in platemail is NOT recommended.\n";
}

int main() {
    // Declare variables & functions
    int locationy = 2;
    int locationx = 2;

    string oper;

    //Declares the amount of space within an array
    int map[6][6] = { {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                      {0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0},
                      {0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0},
                      {0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0}, 
                      {0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0},
                      {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

    while (true) {

        //Asks the player where they want to go around the map
        cout << "Where to?" << endl;

        //Request for user to enter an direction (I.e., North, East, South, West.)
        cout << "Please choose  North, East, South or West" << endl;

        //Displays the inputted values
        cin >> oper;

        //Checks input from the player
        if (oper.compare("North") == 0) {
            //Moves location upwards on the y axis
            if (map[locationx][locationy + 1] != 0) {
                locationy += 1;
            } else {
                print_water_warning();
            }
        }

        //Checks input from the player
        if (oper == "East") {
            //Moves location to the right on the x axis
            if (map[locationx + 1][locationy] != 0) {
                locationx += 1;
            } else {
                print_water_warning();
            }
        }

        //Checks input from the player
        if (oper == "South") {
            //Moves location downwards on the y axis
            if (map[locationx][locationy - 1] != 0) {
                locationy -= 1;
            } else {
                print_water_warning();
            }
        }

        //Checks input from the player
        if (oper == "West") {
            //Moves location to the left on the x axis
            if (map[locationx - 1][locationy] != 0) {
                locationx -= 1;
            } else {
                print_water_warning();
            }
        }
    } //end while
} //end main
```

Comment: Sorry, I really should have added this in my original post but Im very new to C++ and alot of what you've mentioned is stuff I haven't even been taught yet. Also, as irritating as it is, its been made a requirement that my map is stored as an array, and I doubt I could get away with using another system. Thanks for the help though regardless, I really do appreciate it and I'll definitely try it out regardless to see how it works.

Comment: @Thane_Mantis Ah yes, requirements. I'd recommend that you at least ask the teacher about that. That said, if you want me to elaborate on some concepts you haven't heard about so far, just ask in particular. I mean, it looks like as if you have learned at least something about classes? Or is Map.h given without explanation? As for enums, they are not that hard, go through http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum and you should understand how they work.

Comment: @Thane_Mantis Edited my answer, added a list of errors of your code at the end.